# JSF & Facelets Flow

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

I have a dynamic Facelets page that needs to show information from database when the page loads. At this point in the flow, there have not been any form submissions. Every JSF example I can find only shows a form submission with dynamic results on the next page.

Every call I make to our database is currently takes place after an action has been triggered by a form submission. Where should this code go if there hasn't been a form submission, and how do I trigger it? A code snippet would really help me out!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do your initialization work in the constructor (or lazily in one of your accessors) of your managed bean.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Spring integration](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/web-integration.html#jsf-delegatingvariableresolver) (see [here](http://sacrephill.wordpress.com/2008/05/02/jsf-backing-beans-and-spring/) also), it's easy.

In your backing bean, simply use something like:

```
public class BackingBean implements InitializingBean
{
    public void afterPropertiesSet()
    {
        loadInitialData();
    }
}
```

If you're not integrating with Spring there are two options:

1. Load the initial data in the class constructor;
2. In your `faces-config.xml`, you can set properties to be injected. Properties are guaranteed to be set in the order they're specified in the config file. So, just create a dummy property and then within that method load up your default data. i.e. create a method `public void setLoaded(boolean loaded) { loadInitialData(); }`, and in your faces-config.xml have 'loaded' being set as a property on that backing bean.

Hope this is all clear!

Answer (score 0):

You write (with my emphasis added):

> Every call I make to our database is currently takes place after an action
>   has been triggered by a form submission. Where should this code go
>   if there *hasn't been a form submission*, and how do I trigger it? A
>   code snippet would really help me out!

It sounds to me that you want to retrieve information from the database *prior* to form submission.

It seems to me that you want to make an Ajax call to query the database. The Ajax call can fire on a different event than the form submisson event. This will probably entail using Javascript rather than the Faces framework.

Comment: Sorry, I can see why you'd think that. My bad. I'm looking to set these values as the page loads, without any user interaction.

Comment: do you mean staged loading after the user brings up the form, right? why can't the event that causes the form load up start firing additional ajax calls?